# How can I draw a graph that looks like this hand drawn picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to draw a graph with a huge number of vertices. 27! vertices yet I want to express my graph in latex with dotted edges to show that there are many more nodes and edges. Thanks!
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX-SE. Please do some research on the site. Many similar questions and their answers should help you to start. Then you could come back with specific questions about what you tried. If it's not a `tree`, then you just need to draw `node`s and `edge`s, here, using `tikzset` to define their aspect once for all.

Comment: You could have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511857/how-can-i-make-this-graph-look-better?rq=1) which is very similar to your graphic.

Answer (score 4):

There are many way to do what you need.

Here an example with a TikZ matrix:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    mymatr/.style = {
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes={text width=width("$k_{10}$"),
            text centered,
            draw,
            circle
            }, 
            }
    }
    
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[mymatr] (a) {
    &&[-10pt] |[name=k6]|k_6 &[-6pt]&&[12pt]&[20pt]&[-20pt] \\[-4pt] 
    &&&&& |[name=k5]|k_5\\[6pt] 
    &|[name=k2]|k_2\\  
    &&&&&& |[name=k8]|k_8\\ 
    &&&& |[name=k3]|k_3\\[-12pt] 
    |[name=k1]|k_1\\ 
    &&&&&&& |[name=k10]|k_{10}\\[4pt]
    &&& |[name=k4]|k_{4}\\
    };
    \draw (k1) -- (k2)
        (k1) -- (k3)
        (k1) -- (k4)
        (k2) -- (k6)
        (k2) -- (k5)
        (k6) -- (k8)
        (k3) -- (k8)
        (k3) -- (k10)
        (k4) -- (k8)
        ;
    \draw[dashed] (k5) -- +(1,1.5)
        (k5) -- +(1.5,0.5)
        (k5) -- +(1.5,-.5)
        (k8) -- +(1,1.5)
        (k8) -- +(1.5,-.5)
        (k3) -- +(.5,1.5) 
        (k1) -- +(-1,1.5)
        (k1) -- +(1.5,1)
        (k1) -- +(1.5,-.5)
        (k1) -- +(.5,-1.5)
        (k10) -- +(1,1.5)
        (k10) -- +(1.5,0.5)
        (k10) -- +(1.5,-.5)
        (k4) -- +(-1.5,-1)
        (k4) -- +(1.5,-.5)
        (k4) -- +(.5,-1.5)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]